# WLS or Feasible GLS?

Tags: econometrics, statistics, variance, heteroskedasticity

For a question like this, would I use WLS or Feasible GLS? I am leaning towards WLS but my lecture slides tell me GLS is used when there is more than one variable that drives the residual variance.

[image: WLS/FGLS?]

Comment: Hi @theshadowers. Potentially WLS when the variance of the error is known? (i.e multiplicative)

Comment: WLS = GLS in that case (with $w_i$ observed). The method mentioned in your lecture slides should be Feasible GLS, not GLS, I guess. FGLS = (WLS using estimated weights); GLS = (WLS using observed weights). It's a matter of the definitions of WLS, GLS, and FGLS.